# Multiple Db Connection Sql and Postgresq

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, .net-core

I'm trying to find a generic way for multiple db connection support.

```
        private void ExecuteCommand(string connStr, Action<NpgsqlConnection> task)
    {

            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                task(conn);
            }
      }
```

I have 2 Databases which are sql and postgresql. I dont want to duplicate my function 2 of them.
So I need something like that:

if (db == sql)
    new sqlConnection()
else
    new NpsqlConnection()

How can i do that in simple way?

Answer (score 1):

There are a common set of base [classes and interfaces for ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=netframework-4.8).  EG

```
 private void ExecuteCommand(string sql, DbConnection con)
 {
    var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```